# WPF sort datagrid column of datetimes by TimeOfDay

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datetime, datagrid

How can I sort datagrid column by the time of day?
I have two columns, for date and time:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Datetime, StringFormat='dddd, d. M. yyyy'}"/>

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Datetime, StringFormat='H:mm'}" SortMemberPath="TimeOfDay"/>
```

When I try to sort it without SortMemberPath it sorts it like a whole datetime. But when I added `SortMemberPath="TimeOfDay"`, it does not sort it at all.
I tried `SortMemberPath="{Binding TimeOfDay}"` and `SortMemberPath="{Binding Datetime.TimeOfDay}"` too, but it still sorted it like whole datetime.

For example, I have data like this:

Date .................................................. Time

Friday, 1.3.2020 ............................ 14:00

Thursday, 7.3.2020 ...................... 11:30

Sunday, 3.3.2020 ......................... 19:00

Tuesday, 5.3.2020 ....................... 12:15

.

And when sorted by Time I want this:

Date .................................................. Time

Thursday, 7.3.2020 ...................... 11:30

Tuesday, 5.3.2020 ....................... 12:15

Friday, 1.3.2020 ............................ 14:00

Sunday, 3.3.2020 ......................... 19:00

.

But instead I got this:

Date .................................................. Time

Friday, 1.3.2020 ............................ 14:00

Sunday, 3.3.2020 ......................... 19:00

Tuesday, 5.3.2020 ....................... 12:15

Thursday, 7.3.2020 ...................... 11:30

Comment: I believe `SortMemberPath` should be a path, not a binding, and that it's also relative to the row object, not `Binding`. It should probably be `SortMemberPath="Datetime.TimeOfDay"`.

Comment: Thanks! It is working. Why have I not tried the the last possible option...